# I want to fetch all my anchor tags in array with the help of jquery

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am making code which is based on active and inactive links so i want to fetch all my anchor tags in jquery for access.

Comment: This is literally the base functionality of jQuery (query selectors). This isn't a question so much as it is a lack of knowing anything about the framework you're using. Read some documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the anchor tags using

```
$('a').each(function () {
   // would run for each anchor tag, 
   // save it in an array for functioning.
   // to get the text as you said, 
   $(this).text():
});
```

`this` would refer to the current element that it is referencing to in the items. And then the `.text()` method would read the text value of the anchor tag. Read the following link to learn more about the `each` function.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: With the help of this,can i fetch its text also one by one in jquery?

Comment: yes, `.each()` function runs on each of the a tag inside the document and you can perform a function on each of the element. To get the text, use `.text()` method. :)

Answer (score 0):

$('a') would give you all anchor tags on your page.  The result would be an array of anchor tag elements